# Javascript validation - sync with server

Tags: javascript, validation, client

In the interests of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), is there a framework / library / design pattern for specifying validation rules in one place, and having them evaluated on both the client and server sides? It seems like an obvious requirement, but I haven't come across anything like it.

To clarify: I'm not interested in server-side code that generates forms with the required javascript to validate it - I want the validation rules to be decoupled from the client and server side implementations, e.g. request the validation rules through a web-based API.

Is there anything of the sort?

Comment: Would you be satisfied with validating only on the server side (which you must do in any case) and having the *results* of the validation passed back via AJAX?

Comment: @Jon - that certainly is a possibility, but I'm not convinced that it is the best way, due to the delay.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.  I guess I'd set up a class with a static field to store all the rules.

It will need one function to either validate an input directly or return a validator function to be used on server side, and another to be accessed by ajax to get the list of rules which will be tested in javascript with eval.

Theres no reason `$rulesPHP` and `rulesJS` have to be the same.  In fact, I don't really see the point in validating the same thing on each end - you might want to validate different things.

```
class Validation
{

    protected static $rulesPHP = 
                       array( 
                             'positiveInteger' => array('($x === int($x))', '($x > 0)'),
                             'alphanumericString' => array(....)
                            );

    protected static $rulesJS = 
                       array(
                             'positiveInteger' => array('(x === int(x))', '(x > 0)'),
                             'alphanumericString' =>array(..... )
                            );       

    public static getValidatorPHP($type)
    {
         if (!isset($rulesPHP[$type])) return false;
         $exp = explode(' && ', self::$rulesPHP[$type]);

         return function($x) use ($exp)
         {
              return eval($exp);
         };
    }

    public static getJsRules($type)
    {
         if (!isset($rulesJS[$type])) return false;
         $exp = explode(' && ', self::$rulesJS[$type]);

         return $exp;
    }

}
```

used in another file by:

```
  $posIntValidator = Validation::getValidatorPHP('positiveInteger');
  $posIntValidator($_POST['text1']);
```

Ajax with ruleaccessor.php:

```
    $t = $_GET['type'];
    $out = Validation::getJsRules($t);
    echo $out;
```

javascript:

```
   function getValidator(type)
   {
       var rules;
       $.get('/ruleaccessor.php?type=' + type, function(in) {rules = in;});
       return function(x){return eval(rules);};
   }

   validatePosInt = getValidator('positiveInteger');
   validatePosInt($('#text1').val());
```

Of course you'll have to decide how you want to handle things that don't validate.  And if you want to have different messages for different validation errors you'll have to store a message along with each rule and wont be able to simply explode them together.

This is far from a developed idea, but hopefully the general design can get you somewhere.

Comment: Interesting idea with using `eval` rather the defining your own rules data structure. I would want to validate the same things on both client and server sides though; server side because you can't rely on client side, and client side to provide a responsive interface.

Comment: ok that is a good point I see more of your motivation now.  A data structure made for the rules would definitely have its benefits and it doesnt have an either/or relationship with eval.  It could still return a validator function with eval at its center, though a more involved one which applies rules sequentially (rather than ANDed together all at once) and gives a meaningful message concerning which rule fails.  Poster below me has some good ideas concerning how to apply it on the client side.

Comment: I'm not sure that a eval solution is the way to go, Douglas Crockford warns against using it.

Comment: i dont really see a way around using it short of writing distinct functions for every rule and sacrificing any aspect of dynamic use.  eval has its risks obviously, but despite what some people would have you think Crockford's warnings are not law

Answer (score 1):

Nice question!

I have done some MVC validation that gets the rules from database definition. Taking from that experience I would create a handler that takes a column specification string "namespace.table.column" and returns a set of rules to validate, preferably in JSON. Then use css classes to denote the input elements that will be validated (1) and set a validation event on all the ".validate" elements with JQuery, passing the validation object to that function.

Note that with this approach you would have to do some server side rendering of the rules, to not have to expose your database structure in javascript!

(1): 
`<input type="text" id="name" class="validate" />`

The validation object:

perhaps start with some basic type checks, moving on with size checks?

```
JSON structure: validationObject = 
{
    type: 'integer',
    length: '4',
    min: '0',
    max: '10000'
}

function validate(input) {

    var validation = getValidationObject(); // Ajax call

    // perform type check

    // perform length check

    // perform min/max/disallowed content checks

}
```

Not elaborated enough, but something in this direction.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the validation object would look like? And how would you store the rules for each column, or is it generated from the database specifications?

Comment: Not really through with thinking here, editing my answer to elaborate.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer, and it's along the same lines of what I was thinking. I'm really hoping to see something already developed though, that lets me specify (to a degree) logic rules as well. I have some ideas around this, but was wondering if I had missed out on an existing/better alternative.